# Nested for loops running time calculating

Tags: performance, big-o

How can I calculate worst case running time of this loop?

```
for(int i=1 ; i * i < n ; i*=2)

{
     //do something
}
```

Comment: As i is non-decreasing, you can always say O(n). But this is too generous here :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's build up to it--

First:

```
for (int i = 1; i < n; i *= 2) --> log(n)
```

Then:

```
for (int i = 1; i * i < n; i ++) --> sqrt(n)
```

So, it looks like your loop would be something to the effect of log(sqrt(n))

Comment: `log(sqrt(n)) = log(n)/2 = O(log n)`

Comment: Oops, stopped a step early =)

Answer (score 1):

Because `i = 0`, `i*=2` will still `= 0` , and this will run forever for `n > 0`

Comment: sorry it is my fault it have to start from i=1

Answer (score 0):

Formally, you can proceed like the following, using Sigma Notation:

[image]